# GTA 5 big updates every launch, is this normal?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I installed GTA 5 on my PC on Friday, but every time I've launched it since, there have been huge updates to download:

Download history:
Friday-60GB for the initial game install
Saturday-14GB update
Saturday-close the game for an hour, re-launch, another 12GB update
Sunday- 8.5GB update, close game, re-launch, another 5.5GB update
(at least it looks like they're getting smaller :S )

Can anyone confirm if this is normal behavior to have to download so many large update files in such a short space of time?

Comment: Could it be that it detected some of the game files were corrupted, and thus redownloads them before playing.

Comment: Can you give information about the version of the gta5.exe file (Right-click -> Properties -> Details -> Version)? While, I haven't had the problem myself I've seen people having a similar problem (not of the 14 GB download kind) with the game not registering the correct game version in the version.txt, gta5.exe and GTAVLauncher.exe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with GTA 5 is that it won't download each update after each other.

For each patch you need to restart the whole client again. I've figured this much out since installing it last week on my new computer. I wanted to go straight online but every time I launched it, it would kick me out of online and said that the version wasn't up to date. After 4 or 5 updates it would finally allow me to play online.

In the initial launch of GTA 5 on pc the retail version didn't have the day one patch, which contained around 5 gigs of data. They won't update the retail package so of course those 5 gigs needs to be downloaded every time when you re-install the game from disc(s)

I can't provide proof other than my own experience but this is what I figured out through it

But where you downloaded 60 gigs at the start is really weird, it's more like you didn't install the game and had to download it seperately

Answer (score 0):

**That doesn't feel normal.**
The rockstar social club / retail copies got 3-4 updates with the size ~300mb.   Steam got them less (50mb etc., again 3-4 times)

However, it never got **that** big updates.

With the info you provided, we can't be sure but there might be a problem with your game. As stated by Sumurai8, probably the files are corrupted. Repeatedly downloading that big updates might be just a bug, or it can be corrupted files, but it can even be a problematic HDD/SDD.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but would be better suited as a comment.

Comment: @ecnepsnai I think that with the info he provided, this is the best we can say. However, making a small edit.

Comment: You're not correct sir, the first time you install the retail version of GTA 5 it will download an extra 5 gigs after that. I've done it myself and I can confirm it

Comment: @Wouter this answer was posted last year. The game got tons of huge updates after that, so 5gb is expected.

Comment: read my answer, if you bought the retail version you'd know that the very first update you download would be 5 gigs. That happened on launch day when I installed the game